# How to add a post option in wordpress like facebook

Tags: posts, facebook

I need a post feature like facebook post option (ie., when a url is copied from external and paste in facebook post, it retrieve  image and few content to show) 
like this I need to do in wordpress, any suggestions

Comment: **I need** to see user's initiative and previous efforts before even considering dedicating my free time to a question. Please review [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can search for **Link preview WordPress Plugin**

There are several WordPress Plugins to do that, you can find here :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/link-preview